# How do I format words as variable names?

Tags: math-mode, equations, variable

I am trying to find a way to make the equations that appear in this text a bit better looking... here is my suggestions:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        Risk_{i,t}=c+\alpha Risk_{i,t-1}+\beta_{1}
        CEO_\text{PC}_{i,t}+\beta_{2} BR\_ind_{i,t}+\beta_{k}
        Z_{i,t}+\epsilon_{i,t}
    \end{equation}
    \end{document}
```

Here a caption of the equation that I'm looking for :
[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Some options you have for typesetting words as variables include:

#### As Operator Names

The `\operatorname` command from `amsmath` typesets its argument like the operators sin or log.  In particular, you get a bit of extra spacing between *α* and Risk: `\alpha \Risk_i` is typeset exactly like `\alpha \log_i`.

One downside is that the spacing between `\Risk` and `\cdot` will be wrong, so you would need to write something like `\Risk\! \cdot \alpha`, or `{\Risk} \cdot \alpha`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}

%Formatting for a MWE on TeX.SX:
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\Risk}{\operatorname{Risk}}
\newcommand{\CEOPC}{\operatorname{CEO\_PC}}
\newcommand{\BRind}{\operatorname{BR\_ind}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    \Risk_{i,t} = c + &\alpha \Risk_{i,t-1} + \beta_{1}\CEOPC_{i,t} + \\
       &\beta_{2}\BRind_{i,t} + \beta_{k}Z_{i,t}+\epsilon_{i,t}
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: Latin Modern sample]

### As Formatted Text

You can use the command `\textnormal` in math mode to set short phrases of text, and use any text-mode formatting you want.  In this example, I typeset them as slanted, not italic, text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}

%Formatting for a MWE on TeX.SX:
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand\variablename[1]{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape #1}}\nolimits}

\newcommand{\Risk}{\variablename{Risk}}
\newcommand{\CEOPC}{\variablename{CEO\_PC}}
\newcommand{\BRind}{\variablename{BR\_ind}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    \Risk_{i,t} = c + &\alpha \Risk_{i,t-1} + \beta_{1}\CEOPC_{i,t} + \\
       &\beta_{2}\BRind_{i,t} + \beta_{k}Z_{i,t}+\epsilon_{i,t}
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: Slanted text sample]

If you used `\text`, as in your example, the formatting of the text preceding the equation would bleed through.  In some situations, though, you might want that: if you’re using `\Risk` in a heading that’s typeset as bold sans-serif, you might want your math symbols in bold sans-serif too.

Wrapping it in `\mathop` gives you spacing like the operator `\lim`, but then subscripts would be set beneath like `\displaystyle lim_{\epsilon \to 0}`.  So, inhibit this with `\nolimits`.

At Mico’s suggestion, I moved the formatting into a new command `\variablename` and used it to define the other macros.  This also lets you change the formatting of all full-word variables in one place, and write `\variablename{Return}` without having to declare a macro.

#### As Math Text Alphabets

This is what the alphabets `\mathrm`, `\mathit`, `\mathbf`, etc. are for.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}

%Formatting for a MWE on TeX.SX:
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand\variablename[1]{\mathop{\mathit{#1}}\nolimits}

\newcommand{\Risk}{\variablename{Risk}}
\newcommand{\CEOPC}{\variablename{CEO\_PC}}
\newcommand{\BRind}{\variablename{BR\_ind}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    \Risk_{i,t} = c + &\alpha \Risk_{i,t-1} + \beta_{1}\CEOPC_{i,t} + \\
       &\beta_{2}\BRind_{i,t} + \beta_{k}Z_{i,t}+\epsilon_{i,t}
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: \mathit sample]

By default and in most font packages, the shapes of the letters in `\mathit` are very similar to the math symbols in`\mathnormal`, but with `\mathit`, you get ligatures, kerning, and italic correction.  You would definitely notice the difference between `\mathit{fl}` and `\mathnormal{fl}`.

#### Declaring a New Math Font

You can declare new math alphabets like `\mathrm` and `\mathit` as well.  In `unicode-math`, you would use `\setmathfontface`, and in legacy NFSS, you would use `\DeclareMathAlphabet`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{iftex}

\iftutex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \setmathfontface{\mathvar}{lmsans10-oblique.otf}[Ligatures={Common,Rare}]
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathvar}{T1}{lmss}{m}{sl}
\fi

%Formatting for a MWE on TeX.SX:
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand\variablename[1]{\mathop{\mathvar{#1}}\nolimits}

\newcommand{\Risk}{\variablename{Risk}}
\newcommand{\CEOPC}{\variablename{CEO\_PC}}
\newcommand{\BRind}{\variablename{BR\_ind}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    \Risk_{i,t} = c + &\alpha \Risk_{i,t-1} + \beta_{1}\CEOPC_{i,t} + \\
       &\beta_{2}\BRind_{i,t} + \beta_{k}Z_{i,t}+\epsilon_{i,t}
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: Latin Modern Sans Oblique sample]

This example, which uses Latin Modern Sans Oblique, is somewhat contrived because either `unicode-math` or `isomath` define the alphabet `\mathsfit`.

#### Update

Henri Menke in the comments had another good suggestion, saying he uses

```
 \newcommand*\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
```

to get operator-like spacing on the left and ordinary spacing on the right in expressions like d*x*.

If you write the equations the way you did, these variable names should be typeset as operators.  Not everyone thinks this is correct.  If you do not, you should be careful to always write, for example, `\alpha \cdot \Risk` instead of `\alpha \Risk`: you do not want to typeset *a·mass* as *amass*.

Comment: These are not operators, so the usage of `\mathop` is semantically wrong in my opinion.

Comment: @HenriMenke Is there a better way to tell LaTeX to give them operator-like spacing?

Comment: @Davislor Why should you? They are not operators.  However, what I do for the differential operator `d` is `\newcommand*\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}`.  This gives op spacing to the left but ord spacing to the right.  But again, the differential operator is an operator, whereas these constructs here are not.

Comment: @HenriMenke That’s a good suggestion if the word is followed by `\cdot`, but not if it’s followed by `b`. Whether it’s semantically an operator or not, it would be much worse for *a mass* to be typeset as *amass*.

Comment: @Davislor Well for text like `a mass` I'd definitely use `\text{a mass}`, but in the situation here I think `\alpha \mathrm{Risk}_{i,t-1}`, etc. looks perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @HenriMenke Not text, but a variable *a* multiplied by the quantity *mass*.  My own opinion is that, if you don’t use operator spacing around a name that should be read as a single word, you should use `\cdot`: *a·mass*.

Comment: @Davislor Just write `a \mathrm{mass}`, although I'd argue that words for variables should not be used at all in the first place, especially for well-established quantities like the mass that is usually denoted by just `m`.

Comment: I don’t think *a*mass makes it visually clear enough that it is the product of two quantities, *a* and mass.  Much less something like forceps or *du*mass.  Or, *a* followed by e is easily mistaken for *æ*.

Comment: @HenriMenke I think you’re half-right: if you don’t typeset word-variables as operators, don’t use them at all.

Comment: +1. A minor suggestion: Instead of taking a direct approach to variable naming, which requires you to be willing to define lots and lots of macros (e.g., `\Risk`, `\CEOPC`, etc), consider taking an indirect approach. First, define a macro called, say, `\vn` (short for "variable name", I suppose) via, say, `\newcommand{\vn}[1]{\textsc{#1}}`; second, encase all variable names in `\vn` directives. That way, if you ever decide to change the appearance of variable names from small-caps to sans-serif, all you'll have to do is change the definition of `\vn`.

Comment: @Mico That’s a good suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

Not entirely sure what you mean by a better-looking equation, but if you place all of your longer variable names in a text box, it would look better to *my* eyes!

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
        \text{Risk}_{i,t}=c+\alpha \text{Risk}_{i,t-1}+\beta_{1}
        \text{CEO\_PC}_{i,t} +\beta_{2} \text{BR\_ind}_{i,t}+\beta_{k}
        \text{Z}_{i,t}+\epsilon_{i,t}
    \end{equation}

    \end{document}
```

Which would give:

[image]

Comment: With this approach, you would want to use `\mathrm` instead of `\text`.  That way, if your equation is inside something italicized (like an ams theorem), you'll still have the variables looking the same.  With `\text`, they would inherit the italicization.

Comment: True for many reasons. \mathrm is definitely preferred over \text.

Answer (score 4):

I add my proposal, to have another very nice view as output.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

  
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\mathsf{Risk}_{i,t}=c+\alpha \mathsf{Risk}_{i,t-1}+\beta_{1}
\mathsf{CEO\_PC}_{i,t}+\beta_{2} \mathsf{BR}\_\mathsf{ind}_{i,t}+\beta_{k}
\mathsf{Z}_{i,t}+\epsilon_{i,t}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using a macro `\newcommand{\vn}[1]{\mathsf{#1}}` as suggested by @Mico in the comment to have not many `\mathsf`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\vn}[1]{\mathsf{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\vn{Risk}_{i,t}=c+\alpha \vn{Risk}_{i,t-1}+\beta_{1}
\vn{CEO\_PC}_{i,t}+\beta_{2} \vn{BR}\_\vn{ind}_{i,t}+\beta_{k}
\vn{Z}_{i,t}+\epsilon_{i,t}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't need `sansmath` for `\mathsf`.  That package has a very different purpose.  Also the image in the OP suggests `\mathsf{CEO\_PC}_{i,t}` instead of `\mathsf{CEO}_{\mathsf{PC}_{i,t}}`.

Comment: @HenriMenke With lot of sincerity I not remember the reason because I have put `sansmath`. I have edited my answer with your suggestions, and I thank you again in other way. Best regards.

Comment: +1. A minor suggestion: Instead of hardcoding the appearance of variable names (via `\mathsf`, say, take a two-step or indirect approach: In step 1, define a macro called `\vn` (short for "variable name", I suppose) via `\newcommand{\vn}[1]{\mathsf{#1}}`; in step 2, encase each variable name in a `\vn` directive. E.g., `\vn{Risk}_{i,t}=c+\alpha \vn{Risk}_{i,t-1}+...`. That way, if you decide to use upright-serif rather than upright-sanserif for variable names, all you'd have to do is change the definition of `\vn`.

Comment: In the case of `\newcommand{\vn}[1]{\mathsf{#1}}` you can also write `\newcommand*{\vn}{\mathsf}` which doesn't require double tokenization.