# Declare Names as variables in equation

Tags: equations

I am trying to find a way to include  Names as variables in my equation

[image]
Here is my equation :

```
     \documentclass{article}
     \usepackage[margin=2.5cm,a4paper]{geometry}
      \usepackage{amsmath}

   \newcommand{\Risk}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Risk}}\nolimits}
   \newcommand{\CEOGOV}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape CEO\_GOV}}\nolimits}
   \newcommand{\CEOPR}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape CEO\_PR}}\nolimits}
   \newcommand{\OwnershipConC}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Ownership\_ConC}}\nolimits}
   \newcommand{\Controls}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Controls}}\nolimits}


   \begin{document}                             
   \begin{equation}
   \begin{split}
     \Risk_{i,t} = &\alpha + \beta_{1}\CEOPR_{i,t} +\beta_{2}\CEOGOV_{i,t} 
     +\sigma_{1}\OwnershipConC_{i,t}+\sigma_{2}\left(\OwnershipConC_{i,t}*\CEOGOV_{i,t}\right) 
       \\
        &+\sigma_{3}\left(\OwnershipConC_{i,t}*\CEOPR_{i,t}\right)+\sigma_{4}\Controls_{i,t}
       \end{split}
      \end{equation}
       \end{document}
```

Comment: I’m not sure what the difference is from [your previous question?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553236/how-do-i-format-words-as-variable-names/553264#553264)

Comment: @davilsor as you can see from the picture .. the name that i want to include in the equation has two different subscript that are not at the same level but combined in the same expression

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you are asking, but apparently it’s about the double-subscripted output at the top of your post.

If you define a command `\variablename` and express all your variables in terms of that, your sample becomes much easier to write and modify.  You can use a `\variablename` as a subscript to another `\variablename`, although you will need to enclose it in braces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{iftex}

\iftutex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi

\pagestyle{empty}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\variablename}[1]{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape #1}}\nolimits}

\newcommand{\Risk}{\variablename{Risk}}
\newcommand{\CEOGOV}{\variablename{CEO\_GOV}}
\newcommand{\CEOPR}{\variablename{CEO\_PR}}
\newcommand{\OwnershipConC}{\variablename{Ownership\_ConC}}
\newcommand{\Controls}{\variablename{Controls}}
\newcommand{\CEOPOCGOVOFF}{\variablename{CEO}_{\variablename{POC}_{\variablename{GOVOFF}}}}

\begin{document}                             
 \begin{equation}
   \begin{split}
     \Risk_{i,t} = &\alpha + \beta_{1}\CEOPR_{i,t} + \beta_{2}\CEOGOV_{i,t} + \\
                   &\sigma_{1}\OwnershipConC_{i,t} + \\
                   &\sigma_{2}\left(\OwnershipConC_{i,t} \times \CEOGOV_{i,t}\right) + \\
                   &\sigma_{3}\left(\OwnershipConC_{i,t} \times \CEOPR_{i,t}\right) + \\ 
                   &\sigma_{4}\Controls_{i,t}
   \end{split}
 \end{equation}

\[ \CEOPOCGOVOFF \]

\end{document}
```

[image: Font sample]

If you really, truly want an apostrophe in your variable name, this definition of `\variablename` lets you type it in as in text mode.

Comment: As I said before, these are not operators.  Also you might want to reconsider using `\slshape` because Computer Modern is one of the very few typefaces that actually has a distinct slanted shape and doesn't just use italics in place.

Comment: @HenriMenke I don’t call them operators. Word variables use the same spacing.

Comment: I can't recall having ever read about “word variables” in the TeXbook or in the context of LaTeX in general.  But even then, `\mathop` = operator ≠ variable.

Comment: @HenriMenke If you’re having trouble seeing past the name, think of it as short for MATH Operator-like Presentation. All words that appear as atoms in a math expression use its spacing. In some fields, all off them are operators, but that is not the case here.

Comment: @HenriMenke If you want a better authority, see e.g. the equations in chapter 3 of the second edition of DEK’s *Concrete Mathematics*, which use operator-like spacing for “integer *n*“, “real *x*”, etc., which are not operators either.