# Type this: HomC(G,GL(V))

Tags: symbols, amsmath, commutative-diagrams

The symbol is supposed to HomC(G,GL(V)), while I have nothing to do but typing $Hom_{C}(G,GL(V))}$. It can be complied, but I believe that there is something better.

The symbol is supposed to mean that, in category of C, a homomorphism from a group G, sending its data to a group V on vector space.

Since I am unable to find the typesets anywhere, can anyone know this typeset who can help me a little bit? Thank you:-)

PS: This is what I can typed, with the attachment below: [image]

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. What is the drawing? For example I have understood that you want a drawing of a commutative diagram.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Do you have an example of how you want it to look? Maybe a screenshot from a research paper, or a Wikipedia page, or other resource that we can look up easily?

Comment: Hello: I add the image which is the effect of what I typed.

Comment: See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553236/how-do-i-format-words-as-variable-names

Comment: A commonly used convention is that “Hom” (capitalized) is used when the set of morphisms has some added structure, otherwise “hom” is employed. The command `\hom` is predefined for the latter case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your own operators and variables:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}
\newcommand{\CatC}{\mathcal{C}}

\begin{document}
  \(\Hom_\CatC(G,GL(V))\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: \DeclareMathOperator is a good tool, and thank you by the way, despite of being given any power to add "+1" to you:-)

Comment: I care more the way define \Hom and \CatC, thus that is why I accept this

Answer (score 2):

Is it what you want?

```
 \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}
\DeclareMathOperator{\GL}{GL}

\begin{document}

\[ \Hom_C\bigl(G, \GL(V)\bigr) \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 4 seconds . . . ;)

Comment: @DG' ahahaahahah :-) But you have used \mathcal{C} instead of C.

Comment: @DB: Great minds think together… However, note my General Linear group is a math operator.

Comment: Indeed & I like my categories like that

Comment: So you prefer Calcats…