# Problems with Å Ø Æ in equations

Tags: math-mode, scandinavian-letters

I am from Denmark, and I am using a lot of Å Æ Ø in my equations. It gives me a lot of errors, which i would like to get rid of. Is there an easy way to do it?

Also, I am using `;` to make space in equations, is there an easier way?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\centering
TA_{øst_kort} = 3233259 - 2961931.2 = 271327.8 km.\; pr.\; år 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use symbols like `\emptyset` or `\diameter` for instance? And for the A `\mathring` ?

Comment: I was thinking there was an easier way, maybe a package that would allow it, or a command so LaTeX would disregard it.

Comment: Another option is to use XeLaTeX and input those symbols as text

Comment: Actually, not sure you even need XeLaTeX. Just text mode `\text{}`

Comment: Never use `\text` as others suggest, it is not the right tool (it does not do what people think). Use `\textup` or `\textnormal `  and exactly what is meant by the `_` in that name?

Comment: BTW you might be interested in the siunitx package for formatting numbers with units.

Answer (score 17):

Some suggestions:

- Get rid of the `\centering` instruction. It's a text mode command; it has no business showing up in an `equation` environment.
- Use `\textnormal` or `\textup` to typeset variable names and subscript text strings. Use `\mathrm` for variable names (assuming you want them typeset in the upright font shape).
- Be sure to escape the `_` (underscore) character since it's not being used to initiate another level of subscript material.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{TA}_{\textnormal{øst\_kort}} = 3233259 - 2961931.2 
    = 271327.8 \textnormal{ km. pr. år}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You (practically) never want to use `\text` in an equation, since that makes the formatting of the text around the equation bleed through.

Comment: @Davislor - Good point. I'll change it to `\textnormal`.

Comment: @Davislor `\text` is fine for what it is intended for (textural comments in displayed math), this is not such a use case

Comment: You didn't explain the fontenc and babel part, which is the most important part...

Comment: @Stefan - For the example at hand, both `\usepackage[danish]{babel}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` are merely in the nice-to-have-but-optional category. What's most important is the use of `\mathrm` and `\textup`/`\textnormal`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [the methods here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553236/how-do-i-format-words-as-variable-names) to format words as variables, including words in a language other than English.

The string `km. pr. år` is not a math variable, and you don’t want it to be formatted as one.  You can use `\textnormal{~km pr. år}` (if you want the default text formatting) or `\text{~km pr. år}` (if you want the units to be italicized inside an italicized theorem statement).  The `~` is a non-breaking space.  There is also a package for this, `siunitx`.

On LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you also have the option of loading `fontspec`, which sets `\mathrm`, `\mathit` and so on to use Unicode.  This would allow you to use Danish and Greek letters together in your math alphabets.  If you try to do this in PDFTeX, though, you will get an error that commands such as `\o` are not valid in math mode.  This is an artifact of how PDFTeX is paying off its technical debt to the ’80s.

One possible solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertinus} % Sets up unicode-math or T1.
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\variablename[1]{\mathop{\text{\rmfamily\slshape #1}}}

\begin{document}
\section{Et \( \variablename{år} \)}
\(  TA_{\variablename{øst}_{\variablename{kort}}} = 3233259 - 2961931.2 =
     271327.8\textnormal{~km. pr. år}
\)
\end{document}
```

[image: Libertinus sample]

Here, a `\variablename` is slanted and has spacing like the operators log and sin.  I don’t speak Danish and apologize for any errors I make.

Mico, however, raises a good point that *TA* in this equation is ambiguous.  Is *TA* the product of *T* and *A*, just not written in canonical order?  For all I know, it could be a Danish acronym.

Typesetting `\variablename` in a visibly distinct font from ordinary variables would remove the ambiguity.  (I did make them slanted instead of italic, but you can’t see a difference in this screenshot.)  Changing `\rmfamily` to `\sffamily` might help (so long as you aren’t also using sans-serif for tensors).  I’ve also sometimes used small caps.

Comment: +1. Shouldn't `TA` also get the variable-name treatment?

Comment: @Mico That depends on whether it’s a word or the product of two variables T and A. Avoiding this kind of ambiguity argument to typeset `\variablename` in a visibly different font from ordinary math variables. You can’t really see it here, but I used `\slshape` instead of `\itshape`. Changing `\rmfamily` to `\sffamily` might have helped. I also sometimes use small caps.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for bringing that up. Added a note about it.

Comment: `\mathop`? Why?

Comment: @egreg For example, *du* *mass* should not be typeset as *dumass*. The entire word is an atom, and in my opinion, should not run together with another variable like a `\mathord` would.

Comment: @egreg That said, if  the author consistently uses operators like `\cdot` around these variables, `\mathop` is actively harmful and forces me to write a bunch of extra `{}`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. TA is an acronym, and is just short for what im trying to calculate. "Traffic work"

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between “øst_kort” and “pr. år”: the former is a specification for the variable *A* and should be upright in every context, while the latter is a textual annotation.

Also “km” is a symbol and should never be followed by a period, unless it is punctuation: it is *not* a textual abbreviation like “pr.”. The “unit” kilometer per year is not standard, but kilometer is.

So I define a command for “names” and rely on `\text` for the final textual part.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand{\nm}[1]{\textup{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
TA_{\nm{øst\_kort}}
  = \num{3233259} - \num{2961931.2}
  = \SI{271327.8}{km}\text{ pr.\ år} 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a good answer! :) +1

Answer (score 0):

Try using `\mathring{A}` for Å. Define

```
\newcommand\A{\mathring{A}}
```

and `\A` will be your Å. Similarly for the small letter. But I don't think this is what you wanted. Check that you are using a font which supports Danish characters.

Comment: \mathring is a math command. That only makes sense if the wanted input is "A with math ring accent", not to get a text Å. It may look the same but the meaning is different.

Comment: It doesnt help with Ø and Æ though.

Comment: Try these commands: 
``` \AA{} \AE{} \O{} ``` 
They do not work in my Latex, maybe they will work in your project.

Comment: @Quarernion did you try then and did you afterwards look in the log file.

Comment: They don't work in math mode, but the `\text{}` command allows to write them in math mode. For example, `\[ \text{\O{}} \]`

Comment: And `\text` is the completely wrong macro to use as mentioned in comments to the other answers. Never use `\text ` for something like this, it does not do what you think it does. Here this is clearly a named index on a variable name. A named index should always be typeset upright to distinguish it from variable indexes. You may think text gives upright, but it doesn't in general. It switches to the surrounding text font style, family and shape. So if the shape outside math is italics, text is also italics. Not what you want.