# How can I align equivalences using 'iff' rather than \iff?

Tags: align

How can I change this code so that each equivalence arrow is replaced with the word 'iff'?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    Formula 1 &\Longleftrightarrow Formula 2 \\
    &\Longleftrightarrow Formula 3
\end{align*}
```

[image: Current Output:]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\Iff}{\mathrel{\text{iff}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    Formula 1 &\Iff Formula 2 \\
    &\Iff Formula 3
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use `\mathit` or similar.

```
% iffprob.tex SE 576477

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    Formula 1 & \mathbin{\mathit{iff}} Formula 2 \\
%    &\Longleftrightarrow Formula 3
   &\text{ iff } Formula 3
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

With thanks to @Mico for `\mathbin`.

[image]

Comment: You may want to change `\mathit{iff}` to `\mathbin{\mathit{iff}}`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is

```
\documentclass{article}
% Load your font package here.
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\variablename[1]{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape #1}}\nolimits}
\newcommand\Formula[1]{\variablename{Formula#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \Formula 1 &\textnormal{ iff } \Formula 2 \\
               &\textnormal{ iff } \Formula 3
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Computer Modern sample]

I define a `\variablename` command to typeset words in math mode, using the slanted text font, which will visually fit with italic math variables, but be distinct enough not to be mistaken for them.  They are spaced like the operators log or sin, so `du \variablename{mass} y` will not become *dumassy*.  [There are alternatives.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553236/how-do-i-format-words-as-variable-names)

To typeset `iff`, I use `\textnormal`, which always uses the default upright text font.  I also chose to use text spacing, like `$p$ iff $q$`, rather than math operator spacing, like `$a \iff b$`.

If you use `\text`, the formatting of the surrounding text will bleed through, so you would get an italicized *iff* inside a theorem statement.  (Which might be what you want!)  If you use no special command at all, `iff` will be typeset as the product of three quantities *i*, *f* and *f*.  There will be too much space around the letter *f*, and you will not get ligatures.  You can use `\mathit` here, but not for any phrase containing spaces, like “for all”, “such that,” etc.  If you want italics, `\textit{ iff }` would be better.  (And `\textnormal{\itshape\ iff\ }` would be even more robust.)